# How do I make a function in python which takes a list of integers as an input and outputs smaller lists with only two values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of scraped betting odds as well as team names shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssXK1.). Before I can do calculations on the data to determine if I want to make a bet I want to group my data such that odds that are paired together are in their own separate list I can specifically target (groups of 2). As shown in the image, if an odd was provided of 2.15 for Wilsa Krakow this odd would be ideally paired with the 1.64 odd for Hippomanics (eSports teams hence the weird names)the team they are versing.

Essentially I just want to be able to take values from `list[0]` and `list[1]` positions and make a new list with just those values and then continue doing that (`list[2]` & `list[3]` made into a separate list, and list[4] and list[5] etc.) Just not sure how to write a function which will iterate through the list taking two values, grouping them in a new list and then repeating this process til it terminates at the end of the list. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want groups of two (as opposed to groups of n), then you can hardcode n=2 and use a list comprehension to return a list of lists. This will also create a group of one at the end of the list if the length of the list is odd:

```
some_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
[some_list[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(some_list), 2)]
```

This will return:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e']]
```

Comment: Just looked at the example you provided and was wondering what the new list is created under? Otherwise I can't find where the output of this would go to?

Comment: @CalebNoakes i left this open-ended because I couldn't determine from your question how you wanted to assign your new list to a variable. you do something like `team_groups = [some_list[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(some_list), 2)]` and then access `team_groups[0], team_groups[1],... team_groups[n]` for however many sublists are contained